# capture elapsed numerics time in R

Tags: r, elapsedtime

I can capture time in R using proc.time()

```
ptm=proc.time()
tt=proc.time() - ptm
print(tt)
```

and it display time elapsed as

```
user  system elapsed 
0.089   0.009   0.096
```

here i want to store 0.096 in a variable. tt[3] gives both character and numerics

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

even though tt[3] gives both character and numeric, putting it in a collection and plotting a graph works fine. However answer given by Zheyuan Li is more specific.